# Is it possible to get the exit code from a call to exec?

Tags: python

I'm executing a different Python script using exec. I want to determine if the executed script completed successfully or not. Is there anyway to get the exit code when using exec? Is there another option other than getting the exit code?

```
file_to_execute = sys.argv[1]

# Want to find out if file_to_execute completed successfully
exec(open(file_to_execute).read())
```

Comment: There *is no* exit code.

Comment: It's not executing a script, it's executing some Python code inside the current script. What *"exit code"* are you expecting? If that code doesn't execute successfully, you'll just get an error.

Comment: That's not how you execute a script. Have a look at [`subprocess.run()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to run it as a child process:

```
import subprocess
returncode = 0
try:
    subprocess.check_output(['python', file_to_execute])
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
    returncode = e.returncode
```

Your current method of execution does not run it as a process, and so there is no exit code. Rather, `exec` directly executes the Python code as if it were present in the current file.

Comment: Gotcha. I can't use subprocess, I need to use exec for my real problem. Is there anyway to figure out if the executed code threw an exception?

Comment: If the executed code threw an exception, it would throw an exception in your current process.